# Improper synchronization in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

So, I am trying to learn about java threads and synchronization. The following piece of code does not get synchronized properly, can someone explain why?

```
package threadPractice;

public class T2 extends Thread {
     public static int count=0;
     public T2( ) { }
     private synchronized void update( ) {
         int v = count;
         try {
             sleep(10);
         } catch (Exception e) { }
         v++;
         count = v;
     }
     public void run( ) {
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     update( );
     }
     }
}
```

```
package threadPractice;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
         T2 t1_1 = new T2( );
         T2 t1_2 = new T2( );
         t1_1.start( ); t1_2.start( );
         t1_1.join( ); t1_2.join( );
         System.out.println("T2.start, "+T2.count); 

    }
}
```

My expected output is 2000. My actual output is between 0 and 2000.

Comment: what did you mean by **The following piece of code does not get synchronized properly** ?

Comment: Can you put your actual and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well because you make two different objects to synchronize on. If you want a lock to protect one field (`count`) you need to use one lock. Giving each thread its own lock means any thread doesn't know when any other thread is actually using the lock.

First nothing is protected if your field is public.  Make it private.

Second in this case use a static method to protect a static field.

```
public class T2 extends Thread {
     private static int count=0;

     private static synchronized void update( ) {
         int v = count;
         try {
             sleep(10);
         } catch (Exception e) { }
         v++;
         count = v;
     }

     @Override
     public void run( ) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
       update( );
     }
     }
}
```

In addition, `synchronized` and `wait/notify` are low-level primitives with lots of sharp corners (as you have discovered).  A better option is to use the API.

```
public class T2 extends Thread {
     private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

     @Override
     public void run( ) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
         count.incrementAndGet();
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make the synchronized method static (for example because you are accessing instance variables), you can hold the lock in a static internal object. All the different instances of T2 will use the same lock reference, as you can see here:

```
public class T2 extends Thread {
    public static int count = 0;
    private final static Object LOCK = new Object(); // Static lock

    public T2() {
    }

    private void update() {
        synchronized (LOCK) { // Every instance of T2 uses the same lock
            int v = count;
            try {
                sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            v++;
            count = v;
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            update();
        }
    }
}
```